# zlib gzopen() returns a compressed file stream. Does it decompress the file?

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

zlib `gzopen()` returns a compressed file stream.

```
gzFile data_file;
data_file = gzopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
```

where `data_file` is the compressed file stream. 
I may have missed this from zlib docs. But, does this decompress the opened file?
Or is `gzopen()` able to directly parse the gzipped file without the need
to decompress it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Decompressing happens when you read from opened file with `gz` functions. The entire point of `gz` function family is that they allow you to work with compressed files with a C-style interface as if they were uncompressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gzopen` doesn't decompress the data, `gzread` decompresses as you read it.

I haven't found a simple statement of this fact in the zlib docs, but if you want to "prove" it to yourself create a large (several GB) compressed file, and then measure how quickly `gzopen` returns. It "obviously" doesn't take the time required to decompress the whole file. If you look into how gzip compression is defined, you'll see that it's designed to be written and read as a stream, that is to say you don't need to decompress the whole file at once.

Comment: So assume you didn't actually store the data, lets say `gzread` was used to print the compressed file to standard out (as uncompressed text). The peak memory usage of such a program would never reach that of a program that completely decompresses the file, storing in a buffer, and then printing out the decompressed data?

Comment: I can confirm that `gzopen()` does not do any decompression.